# Joining two subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got two MySQL subqueries that on their own work fine, but when I join them together, the second column gives incorrect values.

The two queries in question simply show the total number of times a horse has raced, prior to the current race, and the sum of the times the horse has won prior to today.

I've tried each type of join and joining with different ids, however I just can't find the correct combination.

The output is effectively showing the race by race results.

Query A - total races

```
SELECT
  date,
  raceref,
  horse,
  win,

  (
    SELECT ifnull(count(raceref),0) as totalraces
    FROM results
    WHERE horse = t.horse
      AND date < t.date
    ORDER BY date DESC

  ) AS totalraces_prior

FROM results t
group by horse, raceref
order by raceref asc;
```

Query B - sum of wins

```
SELECT
  date,
  raceref,
  horse,
  win,

  (
    SELECT ifnull(sum(win),0) as wins
    FROM results
    WHERE horse = t.horse
      AND date < t.date
    ORDER BY date DESC

  ) AS totalwins_prior

FROM results t
group by horse, raceref
order by raceref;
```

I would love a fresh set of eyes.

Here is an SQL Fiddle showing my join.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87c54da/1

Just to examine the issue more closely, it's the 'totalwins' column that keeps giving incorrect values when I join the two queries. Or really it's whatever column I add second comes up with incorrect values.

The database is large and SQL Fiddle can't handle anything too large so here's an image of what occurs as it's not immediately obvious in SQL Fiddle.

http://tinypic.com/r/o0x7i8/8

Thanks guys.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." (MySQL does things in an unpredictable way if you're not following this rule.)

Comment: "the second column gives incorrect values." ---> Is it `raceref`??

Comment: Please post sample data, actual results, and expected results; even better, a SQLFiddle.

Comment: To enlarge on what @jarlh says, the problem is likely to be where you ask for entries where `date < t.date` in the subquery. t.date isn't actually known. It could be any of many dates in the group.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts guys. I certainly think it's a group by issue which in turn effects the dates. The second column is the total races which is giving the issue. I'll attach some more information and an SQL Fiddle @NevilleK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date, raceref, horse, win, totalraces, totalwins, (totalwins / totalraces) as winPercentage
from (
select date, raceref, horse, win, 
  (
    SELECT ifnull(count(raceref),0)
    FROM results
    WHERE horse = t.horse
      AND date < t.date
    ORDER BY date DESC

  ) AS totalraces,
   (
    SELECT ifnull(sum(win),0)
    FROM results
    WHERE horse = t.horse
      AND date < t.date
    ORDER BY date DESC

  ) AS totalwins

FROM results t
group by horse, raceref
order by raceref asc
) t
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Neville K - perfect!